# Reverse number 10.0 to 0.01 in javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

I am trying to implement a function which reverse given number(int/float) in javascript. Function implementation is

```
function reverseNumber(n) {
    let reversed = 0;
    const sign = Math.sign(n)
    n *= sign;

    const exponent = n.toString().indexOf('.');
    if (exponent !== -1) n *= Math.pow(10, n.toString().length - 1 - exponent);
    while (n !== 0) {
        reversed *= 10;
        reversed += n % 10;
        n = Math.floor(n / 10);
    }
    if (exponent !== -1) reversed /= Math.pow(10, exponent);
    return reversed * sign;
}
```

This function passes following test cases

```
  expect(reverseNumber(0)).toEqual(0);
  expect(reverseNumber(15)).toEqual(51);
  expect(reverseNumber(90)).toEqual(9);
  expect(reverseNumber(-5)).toEqual(-5);
  expect(reverseNumber(-90)).toEqual(-9);
  expect(reverseNumber(-2359)).toEqual(-9532);
  expect(reverseNumber(12.403)).toEqual(304.21);
  expect(reverseNumber(-12.4)).toEqual(-4.21);
```

The only case its failing is when input is `10.0` . test case is

```
expect(reverseNumber(10.0)).toEqual(0.01);
```

I am not finding any way to reverse `10.0` => `0.01`. can you guys help ?
Thanks

Comment: `reverseInt` is an odd name for a function accepting numbers with fractional values.

Comment: yes it is. will rename it :)

Comment: `reverseNumber(10.0)` doesn't work because `10.0` always automatically converts back to `10` no matter what you do. I would suggest also letting this function accept a string that represents a number.

Comment: What are the actual rules here?  Are you reversing the sub numbers in the string and also reversing the digits of each number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to be happy to work at the string level, simplest thing is probably to convert to string, convert that to an array, reverse the array, and put it all back together — while allowing for the minus sign:

```
function reverseNumber(num) {
    // Remember if it's negative
    var isNegative = num < 0;
    // Get the digits and decimal just for the absolute part
    var chars = (isNegative ? -num : num).toString().split("");
    // Reverse them
    chars.reverse();
    // Put it back together and convert back to a number
    var num = Number(chars.join(""));
    // Return the result, converting back to negative if appropriate
    return isNegative ? -num : num;
}
```

That's verbose for the purposes of instruction, of course, many of those operations can be chained together.

Example with your tests:

```js
function reverseNumber(num) {
    // Remember if it's negative
    var isNegative = num < 0;
    // Get the digits and decimal just for the absolute part
    var chars = (isNegative ? -num : num).toString().split("");
    // Reverse them
    chars.reverse();
    // Put it back together and convert back to a number
    var num = Number(chars.join(""));
    // Return the result, converting back to negative if appropriate
    return isNegative ? -num : num;
}

function test(num, expect) {
    var result = reverseNumber(num);
    console.log(num, " => ", result, result == expect ? "OK" : "ERROR");
}

test(0, 0);
test(15, 51);
test(90, 9);
test(-5, -5);
test(-90, -9);
test(-2359, -9532);
test(12.403, 304.21);
test(-12.4, -4.21);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Re your edit:

> The only case its failing is when input is 10.0 . test case is
>
> ```
> expect(reverseNumber(10.0)).toEqual(0.01);
> ```
>
> I am not finding any way to reverse 10.0 => 0.01.

You can't if your starting point is a *number*, not without messing up several other test cases. As a number, there's no difference between `10` and `10.0`, so if `10.0` (which is `10`) => `0.01`, then `15` (which is `15.0`) => `0.51`). But you've said it should be `51`.

You can do it if your starting point is a *string*, however:

```js
function reverseNumber(numStr) {
    // Remember if it's negative
    var isNegative = numStr[0] === "-";
    // Get the digits and decimal just for the absolute part
    var chars = (isNegative ? numStr.substring(1) : numStr).split("");
    // Reverse them
    chars.reverse();
    // Put it back together and convert back to a number
    var num = Number(chars.join(""));
    // Return the result, converting back to negative if appropriate
    return String(isNegative ? -num : num);
}

function test(num, expect) {
    var result = reverseNumber(num);
    console.log(num, " => ", result, result == expect ? "OK" : "ERROR");
}

test("0", "0");
test("15", "51");
test("90", "9");
test("-5", "-5");
test("-90", "-9");
test("-2359", "-9532");
test("12.403", "304.21");
test("-12.4", "-4.21");
test("10.0", "0.01");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick about the tests: is the `"num"` there a typo? Wouldn't it be better with `console.log(num, " => ", result, result == expect ? "OK" : "ERROR");`

Comment: @noppa - Thanks! Yes, that was indeed a typo, and your code is what I meant. Fixed. :-)

Comment: Thanks for answer. but your snippet failing to reverse `10.0` to `0.01`

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD - Would have been nice if that had been in the list of tests provided. I see the problem, will fix.

Comment: I realized question was misleading. i modified question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the value to a string split and reverse.

The reason `10.0` is not working is because JavaScript is removing unneeded characters in the number. `10 == 10.0 = true`.

If we go back to 2nd grade math class we know that trailing zeros that come after a decimal mean nothing. This is the same with leading zeros that come before the decimal. JavaScript knows these are pointless and removes them.

```js
function reverseIt(num) {
  let neg = num < 0
  let result = num.toString().replace(/^-/, '').split('').reverse().join('')
  return parseFloat(neg ? '-' + result : result)
}

console.log(reverseIt(123))
console.log(reverseIt(10))
console.log(reverseIt(1235))
console.log(reverseIt(-5310))
console.log(reverseIt(10.0.toFixed(1)))
```

Comment: Sorry question was misleading before. I modified it. can you take a look ?

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is use `toFixed(1)` or pass the values as strings. JavaScript will remove trailing `0` since they are not needed. See my edits.